# How can I round up a figure in Java?

Tags: java, math, rounding

Hello I am new to android.
I want to calculate amount in my application. If amount is 35.60 I want to display 36.00 .& if amount is 35.4 I want to display 35.00. How can i do this? Please help me.

Comment: it's not Android question, see java docs, especially Math.round(num) section ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the `Math.round()` method: `Math.round(35.6)` returns 36 and `Math.round(35.4)` returns 35 as you require.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty standard way of doing that, if you don't know about any rounding function, is to add 0.5 and convert to int, like so:

```
int rounded = (int)(value + 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

For flexibility in rounding, consider using BigDecimal like below:

```
BigDecimal foo = new BigDecimal(2432.77112).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
double myNativeDouble = foo.doubleValue();
```

There are other rounding methods available to choose from, check the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/) for more details.